# Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier while setting Forge Viewer

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

i want to run autodesk forge viewer and setting Node.js based on Autodesk [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/run-debug), but got this error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

[image]

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node.js console, you have to use JavaScript syntax and not some `shell` or `bash` code. You are executing `set VAR=xx` here which is not JavaScript syntax.

Since you want to set environment variable you should exit from `Node.js` terminal and open plain `cmd` terminal first, execute these `set` commands and then open `Node.js` terminal with command `node` and then do what you want to do.